# Error build reSIProcate for Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, sip

I am getting stuck in building reSIProcate for Android, the bellow is error log I got :

/private/var/folders/n3/zhf157k55d38k567lgjymyth0000gn/T/tmp.9s8NTMDW/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: warning: skipping incompatible /private/var/folders/n3/zhf157k55d38k567lgjymyth0000gn/T/tmp.9s8NTMDW/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/libcrypto.so while searching for crypto
/private/var/folders/n3/zhf157k55d38k567lgjymyth0000gn/T/tmp.9s8NTMDW/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [librutil.la] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Could you please give me some guide?

Thanks you!!!

Answer (score 0):

reSIProcate links to several other libraries, including OpenSSL and Crypto. This error says that the linker found Crypto on your system, but it's the system version which hasn't been built for the Android architecture i686-linux-android. There is no other Crypto available to link to, so the linker fails. You'll need to build Crypto and any other dependencies for Android in order to build reSIProcate.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I built lssl.so and lcrypto.so already, but don't know how to link them to reSIProcate project. I added these line to build/android/prebuilt/Android.mk file, but it doesn't work 
LOCAL_MODULE := cryto
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libcrypto.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ssl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libssl.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: Hmm, can you post all your Android.mk files?

Comment: Yup, this is Android.mk file  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzgPWgsr6r07Rnc1ODhna1A4M0E/view?usp=sharing .

Comment: And this is build/android-custom-ndk file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzgPWgsr6r07MU9GaDBuWFBIOTg/view?usp=sharing